# Getting Int or Double from func without converting

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my app I have a func that either returns int or double. There probably shouldn't be any issue with converting Int to Double but I'm wondering whether there is a way to make it without that particular convert.

I have a following code which I would like to get working but am unable to do so.

```
struct FuncEquatableView: View {
   let int = 25
   let double = 30.0
   
   var body: some View {
       Text("\(returnEquatable())")
   }

   func returnEquatable<T: Equatable>(returnInt: Bool = true) -> T {
       if returnInt {
           return int as! T
       }
       else {
           return double as! T
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: If the only possibilities are String or Int, why not return an enum with two cases associated with a String and an Int respectively? Using a generic constrained to Equatable is _way_ more broad than you probably need.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: matt, thank you for your suggestion – the func works the way that based on certain variables it chooses to return Int or Double (from variables too). I use the func for sorting and also for presenting inside Text.

Comment: impression: I get "ambiguous use of 'appendInterpolation' – and no surprise here, I expected it but wanted to provide some code for my issue.

Comment: Make the function return a string instead, formatted as an int or double, since that is what you are using

Comment: Your `returnEquatable` function is very confusing. What do you expect it to do if you call `let x: Double = returnEquatable(returnInt: true)`? Types are determined at compile time, not runtime. As written, you can even call this as `let x: String = returnEquatable()`, and that definitely doesn't make any sense.  As other note, if you want a String, return a String.

Comment: I got that idea too -> but won't it be too performance-heavy when using in sorted? because I would have to return string and then transform the string to Int or Double again

Comment: You can't call `sort` on a list that includes both Ints and Doubles. This whole approach doesn't make sense. (Keep in mind that not every Int can be expressed as a Double, either.) I suspect you want something other than what you're describing here. As described, it's not possible, but not because of a limitation in Swift; it's impossible because it doesn't make sense. Ints and Doubles are not the same thing, and can't even always be converted.

Comment: You're right Rob – I can't and I don't. I just use the function to either return Int or Double based on certain parameters (here replaced by "returnInt: Bool"

Comment: Your edits aren't changing the underlying issue. The caller of `returnEquatable` needs to know what type it returns. If it returns "an Int or a Double" that's implemented as an enum in Swift. What you've written is that `returnEquatable` promises to return whatever type the caller asks for (for *any* Equatable type; String, enums, structs, *anything*). You cannot change types with a runtime parameter. Types have to be known at compile time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "an Int or a Double" in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the use case you've described, this solution is to return a String:

```
func returnEquatable(returnInt: Bool = true) -> String {
    if returnInt {
        return "\(int)"
    }
    else {
        return "\(double)"
    }
}
```

If you have a value that you want to be either an Int or a Double, that's an "or" type (the official name is a "sum type"). That's an enum. This enum may work for your purposes; it has lots of little problems, but it may be sufficient. This form allows you to check for equality or sort a collection of Values. (Remembering that not every Int can be expressed as a Double, so very large Ints will be equal to each other.)

```
enum Value: Comparable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case int(Int)
    case double(Double)

    // NOTE: This is lossy for non-integers
    var intValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .int(let x): return x
        case .double(let x): return Int(x)
        }
    }

    // NOTE: This is lossy for large integers
    var doubleValue: Double {
        switch self {
        case .int(let x): return Double(x)
        case .double(let x): return x
        }
    }

    static func == (lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Bool {
        // NOTE: This does not work for large integers
        lhs.doubleValue == rhs.doubleValue
    }

    static func < (lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Bool {
        // NOTE: This does not work for large integers
        lhs.doubleValue < rhs.doubleValue
    }

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .int(let x): return x.description
        case .double(let x): return x.description
        }
    }
}
```

And then your `returnEquatable` would be:

```
func returnEquatable(returnInt: Bool = true) -> Value {
    if returnInt {
        return .int(int)
    }
    else {
        return .double(double)
    }
}
```

Note that you want verbatim text in this case, not a localized key:

```
    Text(verbatim: "\(returnEquatable())")
```

My suspicion is that this is overkill, though, and that your actual problem looks like the first answer, or something even simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You are right the solution is overkill for my case but it I’ve learned a lot.